# xcode navigating from Portrait View to Landscape View

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, orientation

Ive got a simple ios navigation app. My problem is navigating between a viewController that is only allowed to be shown in Portrait to a viewController that must be shown in landscape.

The problem is that the second viewController will not show in Landscape on load. If I rotate the device it will update as it should, but I would hope that since it only supports landscape than it should automatically snap into landscape on transitioning to the view in the first place. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be implementing `shouldAutorotateToFaceInterfaceOrientation:`

Put this in the PortraitviewController.m:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

And this in the LandscapeviewController.m:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: I already have this in there. This doesnt seem to have any effect on the problem.

Comment: the function should be called when the view loads, is it being called?  Check with NSLog's or breakpoints